# mpi4py multiplicating process rather than parallelizing it

Tags: python-2.7, mpi4py

I am trying to run existing code in parallel. The parallelization done before and is used by colleagues perfectly. On my machine, I am running into some problems I could not find a solution for.

I narrowed the problem to a simple thing:

```
from mpi4py import MPI
comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()
size = comm.Get_size()
print "Rank: %i; size: %i"%(rank, size)
```

I am running this with `mpirun -np 5 python test.py` and get the following output:

```
Rank: 0; size: 1
Rank: 0; size: 1
Rank: 0; size: 1
Rank: 0; size: 1
Rank: 0; size: 1
```

Which basically duplicates the code instead of considering the number of process specified.

Adding these lines yield the same error message from my main code:

```
if rank == 0:
    data = {'a': 7, 'b': 3.14}
    comm.send(data, dest=1, tag=11)
elif rank == 1:
    data = comm.recv(source=0, tag=11)
```

The following error message appears:

```
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: Invalid rank, error stack:
MPI_Send(174): MPI_Send(buf=0x7f31851f3a54, count=25, MPI_BYTE, dest=1, tag=11, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPI_Send(100): Invalid rank has value 1 but must be nonnegative and less than 1
```

I found the question [MPI_Send(100): Invalid rank has value 1 but must be nonnegative and less than 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35669614/mpi-send100-invalid-rank-has-value-1-but-must-be-nonnegative-and-less-than-1) but I'm already using the command in the accepted answer and couldn't find anything similar.

I am using Python 2.7 and running on Centos 6.7. Thanks in advance !